# Is it possible to load data from ADLS to SQL DW in DBX?

Tags: sql, azure, databricks, azure-data-lake-gen2

Is it possible to load data from ADLS gen2 to SQL DW using databricks?
I have tables saved in ADLS Gen2 and I want to transfer the tables from there to SQL DW.
If It's possible, how do I do it?

thank you

Comment: By SQL DW do you mean Synapse? Yes. But it might be easier with Azure Data Factory. I take it you are able to mount your ADLS and open files as dataframes? If not, please do that first. Then you can use this example to write a dataframe to SQL Server https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/spark/connector?view=sql-server-ver15#get-started

Answer (score 0):

First mount ADLS on databricks. To do this follow below code snippet

```
configs = {"fs.azure.account.auth.type": "OAuth",
          "fs.azure.account.oauth.provider.type": "org.apache.hadoop.fs.azurebfs.oauth2.ClientCredsTokenProvider",
          "fs.azure.account.oauth2.client.id": "<application-id>",
          "fs.azure.account.oauth2.client.secret": dbutils.secrets.get(scope="<scope-name>",key="<service-credential-key-name>"),
          "fs.azure.account.oauth2.client.endpoint": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/<directory-id>/oauth2/token"}

# Optionally, you can add <directory-name> to the source URI of your mount point.
dbutils.fs.mount(
  source = "abfss://<container-name>@<storage-account-name>.dfs.core.windows.net/",
  mount_point = "/mnt/<mount-name>",
  extra_configs = configs)
```

You can follow this [link](https://docs.databricks.com/data/data-sources/azure/adls-gen2/azure-datalake-gen2-sp-access.html)

Now convert table stored in ADLS to a dataframe. Here you can do transformation with data.

Last step is to store data in dataframe to SQL DW.

Use below code to establish connection.

```
jdbcHostname = "xxxxxxxxxxxx.database.windows.net"
jdbcPort = "1433"
jdbcDatabase = "xxxxxxxxdb"
properties = {
"user" : "xxxxxxxx",
"password" : "******" }
```

Below I have shown how to load data to sql.

```
from pyspark.sql import *
import pandas as pd
df = DataFrameWriter(mydf)
df.jdbc(url=url, table= "Table_Name", mode ="overwrite", properties = properties)
```

For more information you can refer this [article](https://www.sqlshack.com/load-data-into-azure-sql-database-from-azure-databricks/) by Gauri Mahajan